# Python method to get integers from a string with limitation (in some range)

Tags: python

Is there a module in python to get integers from string in given range (with limit/restriction) ?

It can be useful to make code cleaner.

```
def get_int_from_str(string: str, low_boundary: int = 0, high_boundary: int = 100) -> int | bool: # (or False directly)
    try:
        number = int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, string)))
        if low_boundary < number < high_boundary:
            return number
        else:
            return False
    except ValueError:  # Empty message or out of limit
        return False
```

Usage:

```
...
if not amount := get_int_from_str(string=input(), low_boundary = 10, high_boundary = 20)
    ...
...
```

Comment: Why don't you write it? You're mostly there already.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "integer from string in given range" mean? `low_boundary` and `high_boundary` are unused in your function, so that doesn't help me. And how would it be useful?

Comment: Just replace `9` with `low_boundary` and `100` with `high_boundary` (and possibly use `<=` instead of `<` in the condition). And don't return `False` (which is basically 0); either return one of the boundary values, or raise an exception. A function called `get_int_from_string` should return an `int` if it returns at all.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but why do you raise a `ValueError` just to catch it immediately instead of letting it propagate? And for `-> int | False`, are you aware that `isinstance(False, int) and False == 0` -> `True`?

Comment: You don't need to `try, catch`. In the function don't cast the string to int immediately, Check the string to see if it's empty. Also since this is tagged python, I don't think there's a range issue since as far as I know python int are virtually unlimited. The boundary conditions should be using the variables as mentioned by @chepner. So all of the conditions here can be verified and there's no need to raise errors.

Comment: Thanks for a commenting! I adopted a more typos in example code, I will edit it now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That would duplicate the `return False`. And what if they decide that something else should be done, for example return `''` or `None`? Then they'd have to update two separate places. I think it's quite ok to raise that error so that they get into the shared error handling.

Comment: @MYousefi It's a lot easier to let `int` try and fail, rather than duplicating all its logic for what is and is not parseable.

Comment: @KellyBundy look at the original code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did. What about it?

Comment: Why does this have a `try- except` now?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To handle a `ValueError` as desired if one occurs?

Comment: @KellyBundy see chepner's answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's a reasonable opinion, yes. I still don't think that they *"[raised] a value error just to catch it"*, though. I think they did it to share the handling.

Comment: *Sometimes*, you can reuse the same exception handler by explicitly raising the same exception that some other function in the `try` block raises. That could be true here; I'll add an example to answer, though it's a technique I only rarely use. (There's usually a better alternative.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight exceptions. If you can't parse a string as an integer, let the `ValueError` be raised. If the number is out of range, raise a different `ValueError`. Otherwise, return a value that is *guaranteed* to be in the requested range.

```
def get_int_from_str(string: str, low_boundary: int = 0, high_boundary: int = 100) -> int:
    x = int(str)  # May raise
    if x < low_boundary or x > high_boundary:
        raise ValueError(f"Value '{x}' is out of range {low_boundary}-{high_boundary}")
    return x
```

The caller knows better than your function what to do if the string cannot produce an in-range integer, and raising an exception *forces* them to consider the worst-case scenario, rather than letting them assume the function worked and encountering an error later.

---

As a conventional alternative, you can return `None` to indicate the lack of a suitable `int` value. Unlike `False`, `None` cannot be confused with `0`, but it can still be ignored altogether to cause problems later. (And `None` by itself doesn't tell you if the string wasn't parseable or if the parsed number was simply out of range.)

```
def get_int_from_str(string: str, low_boundary: int = 0, high_boundary: int = 100) -> Optional[int]:
    try:
        x = int(str)
    except ValueError:
        return None

    if x < low_boundary or x > high_boundary:
        return None

    return x
```

or, to avoid repeating the `return None` statement:

```
def get_int_from_str(string: str, low_boundary: int = 0, high_boundary: int = 100) -> Optional[int]:
    try:
        x = int(str)
        if x < low_boundary or x > high_boundary:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        return None

    return x
```

Comment: `not None` is `True` same as `not 0`. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You don't use `not None`. You check if the result is `None` or not: `if (x := get_int_from_string(...)) is None: print("invalid string")`

Comment: An exception is better because it produces an error as soon as you fail to parse the string, rather than waiting until you try to use the return value somewhere that can't use `None`.

Comment: I agree. I already mentioned that `is` operator should be used instead of just `not`. Doesn't matter if it's `False` or `None` result is the same.

Comment: And if I'm processing a whole lot of strings where I only want the ones that include valid numbers then I will be raising an exception over and over catching it and ignoring it. The benefits of exception vs if is only highlighted in the type of scenario the function will be used in.

Comment: I prefer to not have to make the check at all, though. If `x = get_int_from_str(...)` succeeds, I want `x` to be the promised `int`, not something I have to check again to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_int_from_str(string: str, low_boundary: int = 0, high_boundary: int = 100) -> int | False:
    number = "".join(filter(str.isdigit, string))
    if number:
        number = int(number)
        if low_boundary < number < high_boundary:
            return number
    return False
```

Note: Using not operator with the output of the function does not distinguish between `False` and `0` as `not False` and `not 0` will evaluate to `True`. Here you can differentiate by checking the output with `amount is not False` condition.

Comment: Returning `False` just makes life more difficult for the caller, who now has to jump through hoops to distinguish `False` from a possibly valid return value of `0`.

Comment: And this incorrectly rejects negative numbers.

Comment: It is perfectly fine since that's what the `is` operator allows you to do.

Comment: And it's going to do unexpected things with inputs like `'1e10'`.

Comment: If the goal is to allow for something like `1e10` then regex would be my go to solution rather than a simple filter.

Comment: That's also what *exceptions* are for. If it returns a value, you should be able to assume it's the expected value without having to do additional checks on it.

Comment: Generally speaking `if` is faster than exception handling since for that a whole other routine needs to be called.

Comment: If the string is good, just calling `int` is faster than making a redundant check. (There is virtually zero overhead with a `try` block that does not raise an exception, and `int` already knows, by definition, what to check in order to parse the string). While you may want to consider how often you *expect* the code to succeed or fail, the overhead of exception handling is generally not as onerous as some believe it to be.

Comment: Each has it advantages and disadvantages. Depends on usage situation.

Comment: There's a reason why `None` exists and why `Optional[int]` is a shortcut for `Union[int, None]` rather than `Union[int, False]`.

Comment: Ok then change `False` to `None` and use `is not None`